# Return html from Tribute js

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using Tribute js to implement mentions on my laravel project and i have written this code.
I searched everything and still could not find a proper solution for this selectTemplate method that is returning html as string.

I want the return string of selectTemplate to be treated as html like this part `<p> test</test` . Is there any workaround or something like that?

```
window.tribute = new Tribute({
    values: users,
    selectTemplate: function (item) {

        window.livewire.emit('create-Mention-notification', item.original)

         return "<p> test  </p>" +  ('@' + item.original.name);
    },
```